# iOS: Swift, great number of IBOutlet and var

Tags: ios, var, iboutlet

in my project I have a big amount of `IBOutlet` and `var` inside one swift file. Do u have any suggestions how to organise well this list? or categorizing in some ways? thanks

Comment: Have you looked at using IBOutletCollection - see [here](http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/) for example.

Comment: It depends what you are doing with them. Why do you need so many `IBOutlet`'s? are you creating them so you can set font's and colours etc. as that can be done in the xib or storyboard. We need to see some code and examples

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `tag` to organize it or sub-class these components, add some properties as `type`, `category`, ... to handle it easier. Anyway, please carefully when you use `tag`.

Comment: Using tags is not a good idea especially when he has great number of IBOutlets. It will get extremely confusing fast.

Answer (score 0):

I can just advise you to add `//MARK: explain the section content` to let other dev understand your organization

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content of this swift file, but usual it's a code smell.

Try to differentiate and separate variables and functions by their responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tons of `IBOutlet`s in a single file, that could mean that possibly you are making a bad code in general. Try to divide and organize UI elements on custom subviews. For example, if you are making a chat view controller, you can split one big view to two subviews named `ChatView` and `NewMessageView`. The first one will contain and manage messages that was sent. Another one will provide a text field with "send" button and another elements like a button to upload a photo, etc.

You are free to make `IBOutlet`s in `UIView`, not only in `UIViewController`.